# Printing specific elements from dig, using bash

Tags: bash, scripting, dig

I'm trying to write a bash script that digs MX on some sites from a list.
I don't need all the redundant information besides what MX the domain has.

So far this is what my script looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash


{ while IFS=';' read un fake
do
        dig mx $un >> tmp.txt
        awk -F ';' ' {print $1}' tmp.txt >> mxinfo.txt

done
} <mxlist.txt
```

mxlist.txt:

```
vg.no;
godaddy.com;
finn.no;
```

The output I get from this is full of empty space an a whole line.

And I would like it to print it like this:

```
vg.no = ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
vg.no = ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
vg.no = ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
vg.no = ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
godaddy.com = godaddy-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
finn.no = alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
finn.no = aspmx.l.google.com
finn.no = alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
finn.no = alt4.aspmx.l.google.com
finn.no = alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
```

Also you see that some queries appear twice or more.
How can I write this better without the extra spacing, redundant info and just one output per domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just using `host`, like this:

```
$ host -t mx vg.no
vg.no mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no mail is handled by 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no mail is handled by 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no mail is handled by 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no mail is handled by 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

...But lets work on your script. The first problem I see is that for each domain, you append the `dig` output to tmp.txt, and then process that. But that means that when it handles the second domain, the `dig` output from the first domain is still in tmp.txt (it was appended to, rather than replaced), so it gets processed again. And then again on the third iteration, the first *and second* domains are still there, so both of them get processed again, etc.

Solution: either use a single `>` (i.e. `> tmp.txt`) to replace the contents directly, or just skip the temp file and pipe the output directly to `awk` (or whatever's next).

The second problem is that the `awk` command, `awk -F ';' ' {print $1}'`, is just printing everything before the first ";" on each line. It prints that even on lines that start with semicolons, or are just blank; in both cases, it prints blank lines. So you get a lot of blank lines in your output. Also, on the lines that *do* have relevant content, it doesn't remove all the extra data besides the MX domain itself:

```
vg.no.          300 IN  MX  1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no.          300 IN  MX  10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
...
```

You could fix the `awk` script to remove the blank lines and irrelevant data, but it'd be way simpler to use `dig +short` to just skip the irrelevant bits:

```
$ dig +short mx vg.no
5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

To get the output in the form in your example, you just need a short `awk` program to remove the priority field and prefix the domain name being looked up:

```
$ un=vg.no
$ dig +short mx "$un" | awk -v un="$un" '{print un " = " $2}'
vg.no = ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no = ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no = ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no = ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
vg.no = ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Note that the MX records aren't in any particular order; if you want them sorted by priority, add `sort -g` into the pipeline between `dig` and `awk`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Worked like a charm, and I learned some new stuff along.
The only thing I would like to know in addition, is what the "$2" does?

Comment: @MCmcoy In an `awk` program, `$2` refers to the second field of the current line of the input file. (It looks a lot like the shell syntax where `$2` is the second *argument* to the script/function/whatever, but they're not really related.) In the `dig` output here, the priority will be the first field, the server hostname is the second, so it's printing the domain name, " = ", and the server hostname.

Comment: Thank you again Gordon! Much appreciated!